# pyspark init super class warning

Tags: python, pyspark, superclass

I have created a class for Unit testing in pyCharm of my pySpark program.

```
class TableLiteral(unittest.TestCase):
   def __init__(self, table_value):
      self.table_value = [x.strip().strip("|") for x in table_value.split("\n") if x.strip() != '']
      # The above code is as part of my development
```

Now, my only concern is the *__init_* is highlighting a warning call to ***__init_* of super class is missed**. Could you please update where I have to update as I'm new to python class.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a mandatory thing, and quite much depends on whether you are working with a real collaborative hierarchy of class inheritance. In other words: pycharm is being overzealous in this case - as one don't usually have to call the superclass of `unittest.TestCase` .

That said, all you have to do is to add a line like `super().__init__()` inside your `__init__` method.

(If you are using Python 2 instead of Python 3 (which you should be using), the call to `super` needs you to explictly fill in the class and instance arguments - so it becomes: `super(TableLiteral, self).__init__()` )